# UIPickerView doesn't immediately redraw unselected rows

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uipickerview, setneedsdisplay

I have a special `UIPickerView` where a rows is manually selected by tapping on it. When this happens the styling of the selected row changes (text color changes and an image with a check mark is shown). Likewise, if another row is selected, the previously selected row is "deselected", i.e. it's styling changes to normal.

Now, when I select a row it looks correct:

[image]

But, when I scroll to another row and the selected row is no longer in the middle its new styling is not applied (Antarktis should be selected here):

[image]

However, if I scroll down several rows further and then back up it updates the row to its correct styling:

[image]

I have the same issue when deselecting. If I select another row the old row is seemingly not deselected and I get this (Antarktis should be deselected now):

[image]

But if I scroll the Antarktis row back in the middle it is indeed deselected.
So my issue is that the `UIPickerView` doesn't immediately redraw the rows that are visible but not in the middle (they are probably cached somehow). They are only redrawn when either the particular row goes out of view and then returns or when completely new rows are shown.

So can I force it to redraw those rows? I have tried calling the `setNeedsDisplay` method on both the `UIPickerView` and the specific rows (which are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`) but it did nothing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling `reloadComponent:` or `reloadAllComponents` on your `UIPickerView` instance?

Comment: Yes, it didn't make a difference. Perhaps this is because the underlaying data doesn't actually change.

Comment: You do not update your model? How do you mark a row as selected?

Comment: The model is merely used to populate the text of the rows. When a row is selected its data is uset to populate an `UILabel`. The selection is remembered by the row itself (i.e. the subclass of `UITableViewCell`).
PS. I have inherited the project from previous developers, so I cannot answer why this implementation was chosen :)

Comment: Your row setup method should reflect the selection, i.e. if you're using `viewForRow:forComponent:` you should check if this row should be selected and update the UI accordingly, that way `reloadAllComponents` will work and you will not lose the selection when a row goes off the screen.

Comment: Actually, I just inspected their `viewForRow:forComponent:` method again and it does reflect the selection. Not on the model but on the view that is returned. Also, as I said, the selection does get through - if I scroll the selected row in the middle of the picker. It's just not redrawn for rows that are not in the middle, but still are visible.

Comment: Son of a... Calling `reloadAllComponents ` *did* work. It's just that the class was in a separate framework, so it needed a clean :)

Comment: However, calling `reloadAllComponents ` has a side effect. My selected row loses its position, i.e. the picker scrolls to the first element. Any idea how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my answer here to explain what I did as a workaround for the side-effect when using `reloadAllComponents` as suggested by fpg1503 in his answer.

Basically I remember the selection and then programatically set it again after `reloadAllComponents` has finished:

```
    // We tell the picker to reload data in order to force it to redraw all rows.
    // Otherwise it may look like multiple rows are selected as checkmarks from previously selected row remains visible.
    // When reloading data the picker will automatically scroll to first row. That's why we will make it to go to the selected row afterwards.
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [self.countryCodePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [self.countryCodePicker reloadAllComponents];
    // We have to make the selection with a delay, otherwise it may perform it before reloading was finished.
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.countryCodePicker selectRow:selectedIndex inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@NobleK Thanks for the quick reply! I tried your solution but found the visual of the picker moving back and forth distracting - HOWEVER... It gave me a great idea: The problem is not actually the call to reloadAllComponents that causes the jump - it's the tap that gets passed through from the gestureRecognizer that freaks things out after a reload. So... what I did was put the reload call into timed dispatch and voila! Works perfectly! :-D

```
// delay the reload slightly
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
    [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
});
```